# Not showing videos in iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have .m4v video files in ~/Library/Application Support/iphone simulator/4.3.2/Applications/ApplicationGUID/Documents folder. But my application crash when I run. And in NSlog, it shows file path null.

I have following code in applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application

```
NSString  *filePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/Sample_ipod.m4v"]];
NSString  *videoFilepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"VID"  ofType:@"m4v"];
NSLog(@"Filepath is: %@", videoFilepath);

UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(filePath, self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
imagePickerController.delegate = self;
imagePickerController.sourceType = 
UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

imagePickerController.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];    
[window addSubview:imagePickerController.view];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that the file at `filePath` exists... you've probably got the path wrong, or the file is getting deleted from your bundle, something like that.

Use `NSFileManager` to check existence.

If that doesn't fix it, please post details about the crash. What line of code is it crashing on, what message does it give?

Answer (score 0):

You don't give us the crash details, so I assume that it crashes because of the null filePath.

There are better ways of getting the Documents folder, e.g.:

```
NSString *filePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Sample_ipod.m4v"];
```

Using `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:...]` isn't going to find a file in Documents, which is where you say the files are.  Use the code I show above for filePath instead.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I have updated my code as you said. But it still crashed. It gives following error2011-10-12 11:19:29.258 ios video email[46729:b303] Filepath is: (null)
2011-10-12 11:19:32.219 ios video email[46729:b303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:]: method signature argument cannot be nil'

Comment: Okay. I can get file path now. I think, it doesn't like this line:UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(filePath, self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);

Comment: 2011-10-12 11:36:28.323 ios video email[46885:b303] Filepath is: /Users/jonathanchen/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/44B36E70-3EAE-4275-BA15-55B7E16AA25F/Documents/sample_ipod.m4v
2011-10-12 11:36:29.671 ios video email[46885:b303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:]: method signature argument cannot be nil'

Comment: In main.m file, it gives "Thread1: Program received signal:SIGABRT"

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I was able to figure it out. I did not implement method(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo. That's why, my application was crashing. It works good now.